# Python programme to find relation between two parameaters

Tags: python

I have the expirimental value of 16 intensity values corresponding to 16 distance. I want to find the relation between Thea's points as an approximate equation,so that i can tell distance required to corresponding intensity value with out plotting the graph.

Is there any python programme for this ?
 I can share the values,if required.

Comment: Can you write out the values, and an example of what you would like outputted? It's not very clear right now

Comment: I want to plot absorption of gamma Ray's my matearial thickness.the value of thickness and intensity are given below. The following is in order of (thickness,intensity)=(0,5.929),(4.5,5.883),(6.5,5.857),(9.6,5.765),59.1,5.834),(141,5.746),(216,5.823),(328,5.746),(522,5.655),(645,5.762),(655,5.834),(840,5.690),(1120,5.811),(3448,5.602)......I want to find the thickness when intensity is 2.9645. I tried by plotting graph in paper,but I can't extrapolate it to large distance. Can you help?

Comment: Why Python? Why not just plot them in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the values you have given us, I highly doubt fitting a graph rule to this will work at all. The reason being is this:

If you aren't concerned with minute changes (in the decimals), then you can essentially estimate this to be 5.9 as a fair estimate. If you are concerned with these changes, then looking at the data it has a seemingly erratic behaviour, and I highly doubt you will get an `r^2` value sufficient for any practical use.

If you had significantly more points you may be able to make a graph rule from this, or even apply a machine learning model to it (the data is simple enough that a basic feed forward neural network would work. Search for [tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/)), but with just those points a guess of 5.9 is as good as any.